# Rails Minitest not running a test class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rubymine, minitest

I have 2 controllers with the same name but in different folders.

The first is in "controllers" the other one is in the "controllers/api/v1".

The first is running smoothly but the latter just don't run.

Both test files are on functionals test folder.

Running test file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'test_helper'
require_relative '../../app/controllers/post_controller'

class PostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
...
```

Not running test:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'test_helper'
require_relative '../../app/controllers/api/v1/post_controller'

class ApiPostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
...
```

any idea why?
thanx

----- note -----

it wasn't running the tests because it missed the test reference in the file name.

and worked just fine with vimsha answer.

Comment: there is no error it doesn't run the tests inside

Comment: I think it must have something todo with the test class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionController::TestCase will automatically infer the controller under test from the test class name.

I think your test should be like below

```
class Api::V1::PostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
end
```

or

```
class ApiPostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 tests Api::V1::PostController
end
```

Comment: hehe I was going to test that now tell you in a sec

Comment: ok the "main" problem was my file name... it missed the "test" reference but it only worked with your answer. thanks